# Proving that $A^{[ab]}B_{ab} = A^{ab}B_{[ab]}$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors, multilinear-algebra

On [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5oeWX3NUhMA&list=PLFeEvEPtX_0RQ1ys-7VIsKlBWz7RX-FaL&index=3) problem sheet, I am trying to show that for tensors (given a vector space *V* and it's dual $V^{*}$) $$A:V^{*} \times V^{*} \to \mathbb{R}  \\ B: V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$$
that $A^{[ab]}B_{ab} = A^{ab}B_{[ab]}$ where $A^{[ab]} := \frac{1}{2}(A^{ab} - A^{ba})$. This seems like a straightforward calculation, but I'm not understanding the following $(*)$ line in the solution:

\begin{align*}
A^{[ab]}B_{ab} &= \frac{1}{2}(A^{ab}B_{ab}-\color{red}{A^{ba}B_{ab}}) \\
               &= \frac{1}{2}(A^{ab}B_{ab}-A^{mn}B_{nm}) \tag{$*$} \\
               &= \frac{1}{2}(A^{ab}B_{ab}-A^{ab}B_{ba}) \\ 
               &= A^{ab}B_{[ab]}
\end{align*}

The instructor insists that it doesn't matter how we name the indices being summed over, and we can simply rewrite the $\color{red}{red}$ term as
$$
A^{ba}B_{ab} = A^{mn}B_{nm} = A^{ab}B_{ba}
$$
which ultimately gives us the result we want. Why can we simply *swap* the indices like this? I feel like I'm not seeing the full picture.

Comment: Have you learned about the Einstein summation convention? When in doubt, write the summation down explicitly.

Comment: @Trebor - Indeed I have, but makes me think: does the renaming of indices come from the fact that $A^{ba}B_{ab} := A^{11}B_{11} + A^{22}B_{22} + A^{33}B_{33}  = A^{mn}B_{nm} := A^{11}B_{11} + A^{22}B_{22} + A^{33}B_{33}=  A^{ab}B_{ba}$ according to the summation convention?

Comment: Yes. You can make that an answer!

Comment: @Trebor - Awesome, I'll add that now! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments:

Assume that $\text{dim }V = 3$, the renaming of indices comes from the fact that
\begin{align*}
A^{ba}B_{ab} &:= A^{11}B_{11} + A^{12}B_{12} + A^{13}B_{13} + A^{21}B_{21} + A^{22}B_{22} + A^{23}B_{23} + A^{31}B_{31} + A^{32}B_{32} + A^{33}B_{33}\\ 
             &= A^{mn}B_{nm} \\
             &:= A^{11}B_{11} + A^{12}B_{12} + A^{13}B_{13} + A^{21}B_{21} + A^{22}B_{22} + A^{23}B_{23} + A^{31}B_{31} + A^{32}B_{32} + A^{33}B_{33} \\
             &= A^{ab}B_{ba}
\end{align*}
according to the [Einstein summation convention.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)

Comment: That makes it look like the sum has $d$ terms, not $d^2$.

Comment: @J.G. - Ah, thanks for catching that. How does that look now?

Comment: That’s look better now, which shows $d^2$ terms explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A^{ba}B_{ab} = A^{11}B_{11} + A^{22}B_{22} +...+A^{dd}B_{dd}$ makes it looks like there are $d$ many terms, whereas there is actually $d^2$ many.

Since the indexing sets is finite, we can switch the order of summation and the terms,
\begin{align*}
A^{ba}B_{ab} &:= \sum_{b=1}^{d}\sum_{a=1}^{d} A^{ba}B_{ab} \\ 
             &=  \sum_{a=1}^{d}\sum_{b=1}^{d} A^{ab}B_{ba} \\
             &= A^{ab}B_{ba}
\end{align*}

Comment: Why get downvotes? The sum doesn’t have d terms.